# OpenGL - Artifacts when rendering lots of tiles

Tags: opengl, 2d, tiles

I am trying to render lots of 2D tiles with OpenGL and strange things happen.

- I have lots of white lines all over my rendering => https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQYl0.png
- When I zoom, this lines disappear little by little => i.imgur.com/H7uJRo6.png
- Until I get a clear rendering => https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDgFW.png

I tried this modifications :

- all TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER/TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER and TEXTURE_WRAP
- playing with UV coordinates
- (des)-activating antialiasing with different levels of sampling

Have you some tips for these kinds of problems ?
I looked for my bug on internet, but I found only zoomed gap problems, not unzoomed.

**Update**

When I did the SSCCE, I found the solution at my problem.

My texture is an atlas with auto-generated mipmap. It's this that cause artifacts.
So I am trying now to handmade my mipmap.

Comment: Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You should post the solution you found as an answer for anyone who finds this question in the future and has the same issue.